# How can bash aliases be configured to handle spaces in directory names?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias, bash-expansion

The alias below works well in `zsh` when spaces in directory names are `\` escaped, but `bash` doesn't handle them properly. What changes would be required to make them work with bash properly.

```
dum() {
  du -h --max-depth=1 $1  
}
```

**zsh succeeds**

```
 user@server: dum "Server Configuration"
32K     Server Configuration
 user@server: dum Server\ Configuration
32K     Server Configuration
```

**bash fails**

```
user@server:~$ dum "Server Configuration"
8.0K    Server/install_scripts
300K    Server
du: cannot access 'Configuration': No such file or directory
user@server:~$ dum Server\ Configuration/
8.0K    Server/install_scripts
300K    Server
du: cannot access 'Configuration/': No such file or directory
```

How can the alias be written to make it work in `bash`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(That's a function, not an alias)

Quote the variable:

```
dum() {
  du -h --max-depth=1 "$1"  
}
```

(That's [BashPitfall #2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target) and [#4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D).)